# Bootstrap 4.1.3, dropdown menu not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4.1.3 and I try to do a nav with a dropdown menu. I followed this example : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#using-dropdowns

However, it does not work.

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot.

**My code**

```
<div>
     <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                 <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Oeuvres</a>
                 <div class="dropdown-menu">
                     <a class="dropdown-item" href="/" th:href="@{/oeuvres/}">Toutes les oeuvres</a>
                     <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                     <a class="dropdown-item" href="/" th:href="@{/oeuvres/livres/}">Livres</a>
                     <a class="dropdown-item" href="/" th:href="@{/oeuvres/magasines/}">Magasines</a>
                 </div>
            </li>
       </ul>
  </div>
```

*EDIT 1 : JS files (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#js)*

```
<head xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:fragment="header">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/popper.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/main.js}"></script>
    <title>Bibliothèque</title>
</head>
```

[image]

Comment: Your `<ul>` doesn't have a class.

Comment: @HamzStramGram It's a mistake, I edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: Are you loading the required [CSS & JS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js)

Comment: You've added the bootstrap CSS and the required JS files? As the 'getting start' section of the doc tells to?

Comment: I updated my question with JS files used.

Comment: Why are you referencing jQuery twice?

Comment: The first one is mine, with `$.ajax` function,... and the second one for bootstrap. If I used only the second one, `$.ajax()` is not found.

Comment: Try to include `jquery` first then `popper` then `bootstrap.js` and at the end include your own `javascript`. **The order matters here**.

Comment: @Ishaan no change ...

Answer (score 0):

I've made a snippet of your code. It seems work as expected.

Maybe you didn't include JavaScript files.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div>
  <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Oeuvres</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/" th:href="@{/oeuvres/}">Toutes les oeuvres</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/" th:href="@{/oeuvres/livres/}">Livres</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/" th:href="@{/oeuvres/magasines/}">Magasines</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it's strange ... I updated my question with js files used (in local).

Comment: Being unable to reproduce the problem is something you should mention in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @zmag Moreover you are using bootstrap 4.0.0. I use 4.1.3. I don't know if it's important.